# Where to find different endpoint properties in ballerina

Tags: ballerina

Is there a location to find which properties are supported for different endpoint types? For example to figure out the properties supported for a mysql:Client endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Ballerina [API documentation](https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/http.html). Select respective package from the right column and under its content, endpoint specification can be found.

Eg: [MySQL client  configuration](https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/mysql.html#ClientEndpointConfiguration) , [HTTP client configuration](https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/http.html#ClientEndpointConfig)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VSCode/ Ballerina Composer for your development, auto-completion within the endpoint suggests the allowed endpoint properties for the particular endpoint type.